# ClassCastException while Unmarshalling XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have generated java classes using `xjc` from an xsd where the root element was `A` of type `AType`.

The root element generated by jaxb is `AType` & no class `A` has been generated.

When I try to unmarshall an xml corresponding to that xsd and cast the JaxbElement it is throwing a cast exception:

Snippet:

`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Class.forName("AType"));

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

AType aType = (AType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes()));`

Exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`

Same code for other cases execute properly and successfully deserialize.

How can I find `unmarshal()` gives me object of what type? I have no clue what's going wrong in this situation, I've tried printing out fields in that `jaxbElement` but it was not very useful!

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the class of the root element (here: AType) doesn't contain the [XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html)-annotation, then the returned root element gets wrapped in a JAXBElement and you have to use its [getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html#getValue%28%29)-method to get the root element.

AFAIK, XJC will only generate the XmlRootElement-annotation if the type of the root element is an anonymous type.

Comment: FYI - You can also leverage the `JAXBIntrospector` to get the value:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243679/when-does-jaxb-unmarshaller-unmarshal-returns-a-jaxbelementmyshemaobject-or-a/10253282#10253282

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this:

```
Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(...);
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

Comment: yes, though i knew what will happen, i still did that! `unmarshal()` gives a return of type `JAXBElement` & that's what it prints `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` !

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707084/class-cast-exception-when-trying-to-unmarshall-xml, maybe it will help!