# Java read XML file and put specific tags into list

Tags: java, xml

after searching for a long time i wasn't able to find anything that helped me. (I'm also new to java)

I have a XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Personen>
    <Person>
        <birthday>2002-03-01</birthday>
        <name>sad</name>
        <comment>Test Comment</comment>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <birthday>1999-02-21</birthday>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <comment>Test Comment</comment>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <birthday>2005-02-21</birthday>
        <name>Test2</name>
        <comment>Test Comment</comment>
    </Person>
</Personen>
```

And i need to get all names and birthdays from the file and put them into a list:

```
$list->:
"sad","2002-03-01"
"Test1","1999-02-21"
"Test2","2005-02-21"
```

And right know i have absolutely no idea how to do that.

Comment: This seems to be what your after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364547/how-to-parse-xml-to-java-object

Comment: Please show us your code and explain your problems with it. If you have no code yet, you should search for tutorials and try something. Then, if you still cannot solve your problem, you can come back here with your code and we can help. But without that it seems you want us to do all the work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the best library for XML parsing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem after i found this [website](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) and used this code

```
    try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("P:/example/exampleFile.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //optional, but recommended
            //read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786607/normalization-in-dom-parsing-with-java-how-does-it-work
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Person");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("birthday").item(0).getTextContent());

                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```